# Dynamically loading content in popup using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I load my json data dynamically in popup based on which div is clicked.

My code is here :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 checkContent" ng-repeat = "appreciate in CustAppre" ng-click = "openBigDiv()">
                    <div class="quote-inner-wrapper">   
                        <div class="arrow_box blue-texture-bg custApprPopOver">
                            <blockquote class="no-bg white quotation-white">
                                <p>{{appreciate.appre}}</p>
                                <span class = "hideContent">{{appreciate.custContent}}</span>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <a role="button" class="customerName blue" href="#">{{appreciate.by}}</a>        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.CustAppre = [        
    {appre:"Project Appreciation",by:"Ziva Roe",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Agile Work Process",by:"Joe Roe",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Customer Speaks",by:"Michael Charles",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Work Appreciation",by:"Gwen Charles",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Leadership Appreciation",by:"Joe Roe",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Agile Appreciation",by:"Sherlee James",custContent:"You are doing a very good job"},        
    ];
```

Comment: Can you show me the `openBigDiv()"` function?

Comment: I just have div.show() in openBigDiv(). What should I write in my openBigDiv() so that popup loads dynamically when divs are clicked. Thank you Ramesh for quick reply

Comment: Issue is allmy divs open on click I want only that div to open with its content which is clicked. openBigDiv function is : $scope.IsHidden = true;
            $scope.openBigDiv = function () {
                //If DIV is hidden it will be visible and vice versa.
                $scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? false : true;
            }

Answer (score 0):

On button you can have a function that open your div like

```
<button type='button' class="customerName blue" ng-click="myfunction(appreciate.by)"> {{appreciate.by}} </button>
```

The button is used instead of the link for it to be easy to understand :)

And in controller you can do a comparation or what you need to show data in popup.

Comment: I do have function but my issue is how do I write/frame my click function so that pop up loads dynamically based on which div is clicked. Thank you .